# Using GridGain as a local cache

Tags: gridgain

Has anyone tried to use GridGain as a local cache replacement? With built in eviction and expiration policies, its very attractive.

What is the right way to configure GridGain as a local cache?

**EDIT**
This is a sample configuration I used to run a simple micro benchmark on the GridGain local cache.

```
    final GridCacheConfiguration cfg = new GridCacheConfiguration();
    cfg.setCacheMode(GridCacheMode.LOCAL);
    cfg.setSwapEnabled(false);
    cfg.setAtomicityMode(GridCacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cfg.setQueryIndexEnabled(false);
    cfg.setBackups(0);
    cfg.setStartSize(1000000);
    cfg.setName("test");
    final GridConfiguration gridConfiguration = new GridConfiguration();
    gridConfiguration.setRestEnabled(false);
    gridConfiguration.setMarshaller(new GridOptimizedMarshaller());
    gridConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(cfg);
    try (final Grid grid = GridGain.start(gridConfiguration)){
        final GridCache<String, String> test = grid.cache("test");
        final String keyPrefix = "key";
        final String valuePrefix = "value";

        final LoggingStopWatch stopWatch = new LoggingStopWatch("cacheWrite - GRIDGAIN");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            test.put(keyPrefix + i, valuePrefix + i);
        }
        stopWatch.stop();

    } catch (GridException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It took around 16 seconds to do 1M synchronous puts (on my Core i7-2640M 2.8GHz laptop). I agree this is too simple a test, but still this is not the performance I was expecting. I was expecting around 1-2 seconds. Do I need to tweak the config to get some more juice out of the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely configure GridGain as a local cache and take advantage of local transactions, evictions, and expiration policies.

Here is sample spring-based configuration that would do this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration" scope="singleton">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="myCache"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="LOCAL"/>

                <!-- Eviction policy. -->
                <property name="evictionPolicy">
                    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.eviction.lru.GridCacheLruEvictionPolicy">
                        <property name="maxSize" value="10000"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

You can start the above configuration as following:

```
$GRIDGAIN_HOME/bin/ggstart.bat path/to/config/file
```

**As far as performance, the issue was fixed in GridGain 6.0.3. The code above executes in less than 1 second for me.**

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question with some sample code I have. I'm a bit surprised by the performance.

Comment: The performance is mainly caused by LOCAL cache being transactional, as if you need non-transactional one, you have an option to use ConcurrentHashMap.